# Scala code to print a Sudoku board and any possible unsolved values

Tags: scala, sudoku

I'm working through a Sudoku solver problem that I found at [UPenn](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cis554-2012/Assignments/scala-01-sudoku.html) (no it's not my homework ;)). I'm a beginner at Scala, and I'm trying to write good functional code (not that this particular method really demonstrates that...).

A problem that keeps occurring for me involves trying to use `List`s but not using `var`s, as per good Scala practice. In fact, `var`s are marked down in the assignment.

In the below method that prints a Scala board plus any unsolved values, I maintain a `List` of unsolved values. However I have to set this `List` as a `var` because I need to reassign it for each iteration of my loop. I don't think that using `ImmutableList` is a better solution.

What's a better approach here? Should I be re-writing this entire method to be tail recursive? I think that could be difficult and the resulting code might not be as readable. Also am I using too many `if`s? Should every `if` be replaced with pattern matching in Scala?

```
/**
  * Displays a Sudoku board in a clear readable format. For any unsolved cells, possible answers are printed below
  * alongside their x and y coordinates.
  * @param message a string to display before the board is printed
  * @param board the Sudoku board itself
  */
def printBoard(board: Board, message: String = "Printing a board", displayPossibleValues: Boolean = true) = {
  val rowSeparator = "+ - - - + - - - + - - - +"
  var possibleValues = List[(Int, Int, List[Int])]()
  println(message)
  println(rowSeparator)
  for (i <- 0 until rows) {
    if (i == 3 || i == 6) {
      println(rowSeparator)
    }
    print("| ")
    for (j <- 0 until cols) {
      if (j == 3 || j == 6)
        print("| ")
      val currentCell = board(i)(j)
      if (currentCell.length == 1 && currentCell(0) != 0)
        print(currentCell.mkString + " ")
      else {
        print("x ")
        possibleValues = possibleValues :+ new Tuple3(i + 1, j + 1, currentCell)
      }
    }
    print("|")
    println
  }
  println(rowSeparator)
  if (displayPossibleValues) {
    println("Remaining values:")
    println(possibleValues.mkString("\n"))
  }
  println
}
```

Sample output from this method:

```
+ - - - + - - - + - - - +
| 2 8 4 | x 9 3 | 1 6 7 |
| 3 6 9 | 4 7 1 | x x 5 |
| 1 5 7 | 8 2 6 | 4 9 3 |
+ - - - + - - - + - - - +
| 5 7 6 | x 4 x | x 3 1 |
| 8 9 2 | 1 3 5 | 6 7 4 |
| 4 1 3 | x 6 x | 9 x x |
+ - - - + - - - + - - - +
| 7 2 x | x 8 9 | x 4 6 |
| 6 4 x | x 1 2 | x x x |
| 9 3 8 | 6 5 4 | 7 1 2 |
+ - - - + - - - + - - - +
Remaining values:
(1,4,List(3, 5, 9))
(2,7,List(2, 8))
(2,8,List(2, 8))
(4,4,List(2, 9))
(4,6,List(8, 9))
(4,7,List(2, 8))
(6,4,List(2, 7))
(6,6,List(7, 8))
(6,8,List(2, 5, 8))
(6,9,List(2, 8))
(7,3,List(1, 5))
(7,4,List(3, 9))
(7,7,List(3, 5))
(8,3,List(5, 8))
(8,4,List(3, 7))
(8,7,List(3, 5, 8))
(8,8,List(5, 8))
(8,9,List(8, 9))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some minor points :

- You create a tuple with `new Tuple3(x, y, z)`, more ideomatic would be `(x, y, z)`.
- You were having troubles with using a `var` and `immutable.List`, it is perfectly ok to use `mutable.ListBuffer` inside your function. You just need to turn it into a `List` before returning, but since you are just printing out `possibleValues` I would just use `ListBuffer`.

Then my major point: I would split up `printBoard` in multiple functions :

- `reprBoard` : a function which returns a textual representation (a `String`) of a `Board`.
- `possibleValuesOpenCells` : a function which returns all the possible values of the empty cells of a `Board`.

You could then use these two functions in `printBoard` to print out the `Board` and the possible numbers for every open cell.

Below you find a possible implementation of `reprBoard` which is a little more functional (I have simplified `Board` to a matrix of numbers, but it should be simple to adjust this code to use your actual `Board`) :

```
// an open cell = 0
type Board = Vector[Vector[Int]]

def reprBoard(board: Board): String = {
  // I have made it independent of the size of the board
  // so you could pass a 9x9, a 4x4, ... sudoku board
  val rowLength = board.headOption.map(_.size).getOrElse(0)
  val size = Math.sqrt(rowLength.toDouble).toInt
  val rowSeparator = 
    intersperse(size, "+ ", Vector.fill(size * size)("- ")).mkString.trim
  val colSeparator = "| "

  // it depends of the implementation of Board if you can map over the rows 
  // and columns, but you should be able to do something similar
  val rows = board.map { row =>
    val cells = row.map ( cell =>
      if (cell != 0) s"$cell " else "x "
    )
    intersperse(size, colSeparator, cells).mkString.trim
  }
  intersperse(size, rowSeparator, rows).mkString("\n")
}

// a help function which adds an extra element every `n` elements and at
// the start and the end
// eg. intersperse(1, 0, Vector(1, 2))  ->  Vector(0, 1, 0, 2, 0)
def intersperse[A](n: Int, value: A, vector: Vector[A]) = 
  vector.grouped(n).foldLeft(Vector.empty[A])((acc, elem) => 
    acc ++ Vector(value) ++ elem
  ) ++ Vector(value)
```

Which you could use as :

```
import scala.util.Random

// generate a random row with two open cells for testing
def randomRow = 
  Random.shuffle(Random.shuffle(Vector.range(1, 10)).drop(2) ++ Vector(0, 0))

val board = Vector.fill(9)(randomRow)

reprBoard(board)
// + - - - + - - - + - - - +
// | 6 3 9 | x 8 1 | 5 7 x |
// | x 6 7 | x 2 5 | 4 8 3 |
// | 3 9 8 | x 2 7 | x 6 1 |
// + - - - + - - - + - - - +
// | 9 1 5 | 2 3 7 | 8 x x |
// | x 1 3 | x 7 8 | 2 6 5 |
// | 8 1 4 | 9 5 7 | x 6 x |
// + - - - + - - - + - - - +
// | 3 7 4 | x 6 1 | x 2 9 |
// | 4 6 3 | 7 x 8 | 2 5 x |
// | 7 2 5 | 8 9 4 | x x 6 |
// + - - - + - - - + - - - +
```

In `possibleValuesOpenCells` you could :

- use your nested for loop if the cells themselves don't have their coordinates
- or use a nested map like I did in `reprBoard` (when you don't need the `i` and `j` to create the tuple, you could also look if `zipWithIndex` can solve this)

`printBoard` then could look like :

```
def printBoard(board: Board, message: String = "Printing a board", 
               displayPossibleValues: Boolean = true) = {
  println(message)
  println(reprBoard(board))
  println("Remaining values:")
  possibleValuesOpenCells(board).foreach(println)
}
```

You need to loop the board twice this way, but I think this is a (very) minor price to pay in comparision with the improved clarity.